# How to solve the matrix equation $\mbox{tr}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H)\overline{\mathbf{B}}=\mbox{tr}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H\mathbf{B})\mathbf{I}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratics, matrix-equations, trace

I want to solve the following equation for $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$, with $M < N$:

$$\mbox{tr}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H)\overline{\mathbf{B}}=\mbox{tr}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H\mathbf{B})\mathbf{I}$$

where $\mathbf{B}$ is a known $N\times N$ Hermitian positive semidefinite matrix, and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. $\overline{\mathbf{B}}$ means the complex conjugate of $\mathbf{B}$.

I have tried to express $\mathbf{B}$ as $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H$, and got the following equation

$$
\mbox{tr}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H)\overline{\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H}=\mbox{tr}(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H)\mathbf{I} = \mathbf{b}^H\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^H\mathbf{b}\mathbf{I}
$$

but still hard to solve.

I also tried to vectorize the matrix, and got

$$ \mbox{vec}^H(\mathbf{X})\mbox{vec}(\mathbf{X})\overline{\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H}=\mbox{vec}^H(\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{X}^H \otimes \mathbf{I})\mbox{vec}(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H)\mathbf{I} = \mbox{vec}^H(\mathbf{X})\mbox{vec}(\mathbf{b}\mathbf{b}^H \mathbf{X}^H)\mathbf{I}
$$

But I have no idea how to solve this, could someone please help me with that?

Comment: You have $\binom{N+1}{2}$ equations in $N M$ unknowns. Please define "solve".

Comment: It should be clear that either $\mathbf{B}=\lambda\cdot \mathbf{I}$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ (and $\mathbf{X}$ is arbitrary) or $\mathbf{X}=0$). Note that your equation is of the form $a\cdot \mathbf{B}^*=b\cdot \mathbf{I}$, where $a$ and $b$ are some constants.

Comment: Your symbols are confusing. In linear algebra literature, **both** $B^\ast$ and $B^H$ mean the conjugate transpose of $B$. What is the $B^\ast$ in your question? If you mean complex conjugate, please change it to the standard notation $\overline{B}$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, "conjugate symmetry" means Hermitian. "solve" means to find the closed form expression of $\mathbf{X}$.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks, I have edited it again.

Comment: @richrow Yes, is it possible to find the expression of $\mathbf{X}$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I'm not sure if there is a unique solution or not.

Comment: So do you want to parameterise the set of solutions?

Comment: Yes, that also helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $X=0$ is a solution.

Now suppose $X\ne0$. Then $XX^H$ is a nonzero positive semidefinite matrix. Therefore $\operatorname{tr}(XX^H)>0$ and the equation implies that $\overline{B}=kI$ where $k=\frac{\operatorname{tr}(XX^HB)}{\operatorname{tr}(XX^H)}$. The equation can therefore be rewritten as $\operatorname{tr}(XX^H)\overline{k}I=\operatorname{tr}(kXX^H)I$ and further be rewritten as $\operatorname{tr}(XX^H)\overline{k}I=\operatorname{tr}(XX^H)kI$. Since $\operatorname{tr}(XX^H)>0$, it is solvable only if $k$ is real. If this is the case, every nonzero $X$ is a solution.

So, in summary, every (zero or nonzero) $X$ is a solution when $B$ is a real scalar multiple of $I$, or $X=0$ is the only solution otherwise.